# How load or add minified third party libraries into webpack application?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I have a lot of old libraries which I need to include them in my javascript application, but I have several errors due to webpack.

I reproduce the error with:

- [webpack-starter sample](https://github.com/software-architect-tools/webpack-starter)
- jquery script downloaded from https://code.jquery.com/

**#1**

If I add the **minified** version `<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"/>` into index.html I get this error:

```
WARNING in ./src/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):

/tmp/workspacew/webpack-starter/src/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
  2:218    error  Missing semicolon  semi
  2:224    error  Missing semicolon  semi
  2:377    error  Missing semicolon  semi
  2:418    error  Missing semicolon  semi
  2:582    error  Missing semicolon  semi
  <a lot of similar lines>

@ ./src/index.html 3:33-65
@ ./src/scripts/index.js

ERROR in   Error: webpack-internal:///./src/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:116
E = C.document,
     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

- jquery-3.5.1.min.js:116 eval
webpack-internal:///./src/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:116:13
```

**#2**

If I add the **uncompressed** version `<script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"/>` into index.html I have a similar error (without `Missing semicolon` error lines):

```
ERROR in   Error: webpack-internal:///./src/jquery-3.5.1.js:154
var document = window.document;
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

**#3**

If I add `import '../jquery-3.5.1.min.js';` in my entry index.js, I get the same error lines with: `Missing semicolon`.

**#4**

If I add `import '../jquery-3.5.1.js';` in my entry index.js, jquery **is correctly loaded.** But this is not my case because my files are already minified.

**My question is**

How can I use third party libraries (not as npm modules) already minified in a simple way like:

`<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"/>`

Must I manually load them in my **index.js** ?

**Research, Attempts, Workarounds**

- **webpack-merge-and-include-globally**

  - This claims to merge all third party libraries in one vendor.js file. But according to my attempt, [just work after build process](https://github.com/markshapiro/webpack-merge-and-include-globally/issues/43)
- Host minified files in another server and using

`<script src="htt://another.host.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"/>`, works!

- Next Attempt: Use https://github.com/shoutem/webpack-prepend-append to add minified files :s